# Array var in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to figure out how to create a var in Sql Server which contains an array of values, searched here in Stack but nothing consistent... this is how I imagined it could be like:

```
declare @partners as nvarchar(max) = ('partner1','partner2');

select * from partners
where partner in (@partners);
```

Is it possible in SQL Server? How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with table

```
declare @partnersList as table(partnerName  varchar(100))
insert into @partnersList values('partner1'),('partner2')

SELECT * 
FROM partners
WHERE 'partner' in (SELECT partnerName FROM @partnersList)
```

Comment: Disappointed that SQL Server do not support this kind of logic, but this solution is useful and solved my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can't do so, but you can use a table variable to get the same behavior:

```
declare @partners TABLE (
    Name nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT @partners
VALUES
    ('partner1'),
    ('partner2')

select * from partners
where partner in (
    SELECT Name 
    FROM @partners
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can execute it as dynamic:

```
declare @partners as nvarchar(max) = ' ''partner1'',''partner2'' '


declare @sql nvarchar(Max)

Set @sql='SELECT * FROM partners WHERE [partner] IN ('+ @partners +')'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: This exposes the code to SQL injection and should be, really, the very last resort.