# SQL Server variable datetime with array

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Can we define a variable of type array in SQL Server?

I have a table and this pk type is `datetime`.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblTest]
(
    [TestDate] [datetime] NOT NULL, -- this column is the primary key
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RotationType] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

And I need a query to update `userId`

```
UPDATE TABLE dbo.tblTest
SET RotationType = 1
WHERE TestDate IN (@testDates)
```

How can I declare this `@testDates` variable?

Comment: TABLE variables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array var in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46827223/array-var-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: There's no `TABLE` in the `UPDATE` statement - just use `UPDATE dbo.tblTest SET ....`

Answer (score 2):

you can use `table variables`:

```
declare @tblvar as table (TestDate datetime)

insert into @tblvar  values (('2021-09-01'),...);

UPDATE TABLE dbo.tblTest
SET RotationType = 1
WHERE TestDate IN (select TestDate from @tblvar)
```

or you can declare it as type so you can pass it to procs:

declaration phase :

```
create type DateTimeArray as table (TestDate datetime);

CREATE PROCEDURE funcname (@inputDates DateTimeArray)
as
UPDATE TABLE dbo.tblTest
SET RotationType = 1
WHERE TestDate IN (select TestDate from @inputDates)
end
```

calling:

```
declare @tblvar as DateTimeArray;

insert into @tblvar  values (('2021-09-01'),...);
exec funcname @tblvar
```

Comment: i will use this variables in sp, so i need pass this parameter how can i it ?

Comment: see my updated asnwer , didn't test , so it might have some minor syntax issue , but you got the idea ;)